# How to echo contents of $GLOBAL?

Tags: php

I am trying to print the contents of $GLOBAL variable but my code gives errors. Please guide me.

```
<?php
    echo gettype($GLOBALS); // confirming the type of $GLOBALS
    foreach ($GLOBALS as $value)
        echo $value."<br>";
?>
```

Output:

```
array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 4
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 4
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 4
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 4
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 4
Array

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\first.php on line 4
Array
Array to string conversion
```

Comment: Do: `print_r($GLOBALS);` and see the structure of the array.

Comment: Or `var_dump($GLOBALS)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this Function it will print it all right away.

```
function printArray($array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            //Check if the Value is not recursive
            if ($key != 'GLOBALS') {
                //If the returning value is Array than call back function
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    // recursive function
                    printArray($value);
                } else {
                    //Once returning value is not Array
                    echo $value."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Calling the function
printArray($GLOBALS);
```

Comment: `$GLOBALS` does not have to contain only arrays.

Comment: @ShanKhaliq Now you maybe want to explain what you do here with this function and why.

Comment: I simply check the structure of the array so i tells me that at the end this array is recursive so i put a condition for if the `$value` is `GLOBALS` than do nothing and if `$value` array than recall my function but if the value is not array than print the `$value`

Comment: @ShanKhaliq ^^ Put this into your answer, so more people will understand your code/answer.

Comment: i'm pretty new to helping people on forms so i forget to add comments in my code sorry for that. please the select the answer for other's help :)

Comment: FYI: 1) SO is a Q&A site not a forum :) 2) See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer it might help to write better answers in the future. 3) If you write the explanation outside of the code it makes the code more readable.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for explaining i'll be working on this now on

Answer (score -1):

Try this,"print_r($GLOBAL)" as, I am currently concentrating in jsp I couldn't say pricisely that this will work, but try out the above statement, it might work there is a possibility bec I had worked it out I guess ....,, I don't remember when I had worked...